# Как записать натуральный логарифм поднесен к квадрату в С++?

Tags: c++

Есть у меня пример: y=ln²(x). Как его записать в коде программы?

Comment: Так стоп за что плохую оценку вопросу? Я могу исправить… Я до сих пор не понимаю большинство негативных оценок почему, вам один клик, а мне минус балы и после большинство просто не уберет негативную оценку даже после правок(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто возвести в квадрат.

```
double y = log(x);
y = y*y;
```

Comment: Тоисть _y = pow(log(x),2)_?

Comment: Лучше умножать. Эффективнее.

Comment: На доном примере вполне, но иногда заставлять соответственно функции и если так как выше написано предъявлять будто не знаю операцию pow.